# Internal diagrams in a fibration are monadic

Tags: ct.category-theory

[image: Definition of an internal diagram of a fibration, from Definition 7.4.1 of Bart Jacobs' *Categorical Logic and Type Theory*]

I am reading "Categorical Logic and Type Theory* by Bart Jacobs.

In *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* by Mac Lane and Moerdijk, they prove that in the setting depicted, if we set $\mathbb{B}$ to be an elementary topos, and $\mathbb{E}$ to be the codomain fibration, then the category of internal diagrams and internal 'natural transformations' between them is monadic over $\mathbb{E}_{C_0}$.

I am trying to extend this proof to the more general case where $p$ is just any fibration satisfying some nice properties - i.e. $\mathbb{B}$ has finite limits, $p$ has left and right adjoints to the pullback functors satisfying Beck-Chevalley, and stuff like that. I have defined the functor easily enough; it should just be what Jacobs would denote $\coprod_{\partial_1}\circ\partial_0^\ast$. The unit, I have also been able to construct diagrammatically. However the multiplication map I have trouble phrasing diagramatically.

I would like someone to tell me whether I'm correct about this result and show me the construction of the monad. Any resources where this is shown (preferably in a larger context where there are some applications for these ideas talked about) would be appreciated. To me this is interesting but is this fact useful for anything?

Edit: with some renewed effort I have successfully constructed the maps. I did use Beck-Chevalley for left adjoints where the base square is a pullback square; I did not use right adjoints. I still have to hack my way through a proof that they satisfy the desired formal laws and that the algebra map makes it into a presheaf; but this seems relatively straightforward. But my other question still stands. Is this a known result (I am sure it is, being an easy exercise), and where can I find a reference that proves this in context?

Comment: I think Proposition 4.6.1. of Borceux and Janelidze's book "Galois Theories" is what you're looking for. When the internal category is the kernel pair of a morphism $p$, the monad coincides with the one induced by the adjunction $p_*\dashv p^*$, and this is the basis of monadic descent; see for example Janelidze and Tholen's "Facets of descent I".